# Symbol OR end of line pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need a pattern (java regexp) which matches if there is a comma after key or key is at the end of line. i.e it should match both of followings:

```
1. xxxkey,yyy
2. xxxkey
```

Ive tried `[\\,$]` pattern but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$` inside a character class loses its special meaning. Use the following instead:

```
key(,|$)
```

If you don't need to know whether there was a comma, you can use a non-capturing group instead:

```
key(?:,|$)
```

Comment: How would you escape characters with special meaning inside character classes?

Comment: @Oliver: It's not simply a matter of escaping the `$`. Since it's an anchor rather than a character, I don't think you can put into a character class *at all* without it losing its special meaning. In any case, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for the Java regex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
"xxxkey(?:,\\w*)?$"
```

or -

```
"xxxkey(?:,.*)?$"
```

or -

```
"xxxkey(?:,|$)"
```

Depending on your needs

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need :

```
.*key((,.*)|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `,` is a character, but the `$` is special, it's not a character.

Try `,?` which means one comma or no commas and follow that with `$`.